# Why log4j console output same result as file

Tags: console, log4j

As I just begin learning log4j, this project is just a log4j-demo to print log info. And wanna print the console log and file log with different information. This should be not difficult but I don't know why it failed.

Hope you can help me figure it out. Thanks.

This is the log4j.properties:

```
#  Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, console, file

#  Define the console appender
log4j.appender.console = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Threshold = DEBUG
log4j.appender.console.Target = System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layput.conversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p -%C- - %m%n

## Define the file appender
log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.Threshold = INFO
log4j.appender.file.File = ./log.out
log4j.appender.file.Append = true
log4j.appender.file.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.conversionPattern = %m%n
```

This is the log4j main class:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class Log4jExample {
   static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Log4jExample.class.getName());
   public static void main(String[] args){
       log.trace("Trace Message!");
       log.debug("Debug Message!");
       log.info("Info Message!");
       log.warn("Warn Message!");
       log.error("Error Message!");
       log.fatal("Fatal Message!");
   }
}
```

This is the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.yizhang</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Log4jExample</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is the output image:
    [screencut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zwdn.png)

Comment: log4j.appender.console.layput.conversionPattern - layput?

Comment: >< so stupid. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the typo `layput`.

```
#  Define the console appender
log4j.appender.console = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Threshold = DEBUG
log4j.appender.console.Target = System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p -%C- - %m%n
```